# How to use prototype for custom methods and object manipulation

Tags: javascript, prototype

Honestly, I am trying to understand JavaScript prototypes and I'm not making much progress.  I am not exactly sure how to explain what I am trying to do, except to say that in part my end goal is to learn how to traverse the DOM similar to jQuery and to add custom methods to manipulate particular elements being accessed.

**EDIT :** The code below has been updated to reflect concepts I have learned from the answers received so far, and to show where those fall short of what I am looking to accomplish.

```
function A(id) {
    "use strict";
    this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
}
A.prototype.insert = function (text) {
    "use strict";
    this.elem.innerHTML = text;
};

var $A = function (id) {
    "use strict";
    return new A(id);
};

var $B = function (id) {
    "use strict";
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

function init() {
    "use strict";
    $A('para1').insert('text goes here'); //this works
    $A('para1').innerHTML = 'text goes here';  //this does not work
    console.log($A('para1')); //returns the object A from which $A was constructed
    console.log($B('para1')); //returns the dom element... this is what I want

    /*I want to have $A('para1').insert(''); work and $A('para1').innerHTML = '';
      work the same way that $B('para1').innerHTML = ''; works and still be able
      to add additional properties and methods down the road that will be able
      act directly on the DOM element that is contained as $A(id) while also
      being able to use the properties and methods already available within
      JavaScript*/
}
window.onload = init;
```

Where possible please add an explanation of why your code works and why you believe it is the best possible method for accomplishing this.

**Note:** The whole purpose of my inquiry is to learn this on my own... please do not suggest using jQuery, it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $ = function(id) {  
    return new My_jquery(id);  
}  

function My_jquery(id) { 
    this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
}

My_jquery.prototype = {
   insert : function(text) { this.elem.innerHtml = text; return this;}
}

$('para1').insert('hello world').insert('chaining works too');
```

add any method u want to operate on elem in My_jquery.prototype

Comment: I have been fiddling around with this code and the problem is that when I leave it the way you have written it then:
`$('para1').innerHTML = 'this works'; //Does not work anymore`
wouldn't you want to maintain accessibility to all standard methods?

Comment: you will need to write a html method in the prototype, like in jQuery.

Comment: @yngum—jQuery doesn't work that way either, you'd need to do $('#foo')[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: yeah I was trying to find a way around this, but I suppose that's what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var getDOM= function(id) {
  this.element= document.getElementById(id);
}

getDOM.prototype.insert= function(content) {
  this.element.innerHTML= content;
}

var $= function(id) {
  return new getDOM(id);
};

$('id').insert('Hello World!'); // can now insert 'Hello World!' into document.getElementById('id')
```

Comment: Upvotes for non–working code? Note that objects inherit from their constructor's prototype, not their own. `$` doesn't have an *insert* method, so the above throws a type error. You need to remove the return from the *$* function, then do: `(new $('id')).insert('Hello World!');`.

Comment: See comment on @yngum 's answer, the same applies to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scheme like the following:

```
function $(id) {
  return new DOMNode(id);
}

function DOMNode(id) {
  this.element = document.getElementById(id);
}

DOMNode.prototype.insert = function(value) {

  if (value) {

    // If value is a string, assume its markup
    if (typeof value == 'string') {
      this.element.innerHTML = value;

    // Otherwise assume it's an object
    } else {

      // If it's a DOM object
      if (typeof value.nodeName == 'string') {
        this.element.appendChild(value);

      // If it's a DOMNode object
      } else if (this.constructor == DOMNode) {
        this.element.appendChild(value.element);
      }
    }
  } // If all fails, do nothing
}

$('id').insert('foo bar');
```

Some play stuff:

```
<div id="d0">d0</div>
<div id="d1">d1</div>
<div id="d2">d2</div>

<script>
// insert (replace content with) string, may or may not be HTML
$('d0').insert('<b>foo bar</b>');

// insert DOMNode object
$('d0').insert($('d1'));

// Insert DOM element
$('d0').insert(document.getElementById('d2'));

</script>
```

You may find it useful to study how [MyLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html) works, it has some very good practices and patterns.

Comment: See comment on @yngum 's answer, the same applies to yours.